# GtkTreeView expand/collapse on keypress events

Tags: gtk

Is there an elegant way to expand/collapse the items in a *GtkTreeView* using the keyboard (say, the Enter key)?The view only seems to be responding to mouse clicks by default.I should perhaps connect the

```
"key_press_event"
```

signal to the view and in the handler, check

```
gtk_tree_view_row_expanded ()
```

and call

```
gtk_tree_view_expand_row ()
```

(with corresponding actions for collapse).

Answer (score 1):

The `row-activated` signal was the better (right) callback choice instead of the `key_press_event`. Gave me all the parameters need to use `gtk_tree_view_expand_row()` and `gtk_tree_view_collapse_row()`. Works as expected.